# Joda time, Period to total millis

Tags: java, jodatime

I'm trying to get the *total* amount of Milliseconds (*not* the millis field) from the Period object instance. I've tried multiple conversions, as I couldn't find any method easily giving it.

Has anyone ever needed that and managed to retrieve it ?

(I need this for my patch, to figure out a negative period; negative millis = negative period.)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can't get the millis directly from a `Period`, since fields like months and years are variable in terms of milliseconds.

In order to make this work, you need to supply a "baseline" instant from which `Period` can calculate that actual millisecond duration.

For example, the `Period.toDurationFrom` and `Period.toDurationTo` methods take such a baseline instant, and calculate a `Duration` object, which you can then obtain the millis.

The [Javadoc](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/base/BasePeriod.html#toDurationFrom%28org.joda.time.ReadableInstant%29) for `toDurationFrom` says:

> Gets the total millisecond duration of this period relative to a start instant.
>   This method adds the period to the specified instant in order to calculate the duration.
>
> An instant must be supplied as the duration of a period varies. For example, a period of 1 month could vary between the equivalent of 28 and 31 days in milliseconds due to different length months. Similarly, a day can vary at Daylight Savings cutover, typically between 23 and 25 hours.

So you need to pick an appropriate baseline instant for your application.

Comment: got it:

DateTime zero = new DateTime(0);
long millis = period.toDurationFrom(zero).getMillis();

Comment: @DrorWeiss: That will work for relatively small periods only.  If you start using periods longer than a month, then that may give you a distorted result.

Comment: i've tested it.. so far looks good. though, i will keep watch. Thanks ! ;)

Comment: `toStandardDuration().toMillis()` is a good approximation if you don't expect any  weirdness.

Comment: @skaffman - do you mean wrap around due to limitation in size of long ? If yes, then should i use BigDecimal instead ?

Comment: In my version of joda time (2.3) it seems to be: `toStandardDuration().getMillis()`

Comment: @WimDeblauwe You could add this as answer.

Comment: @Knight71 just did now.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to get the millis from a **specific** time it can be done by using the plus() or minus() methods of the DateTime class.

e.g. getting the millis from **now**

```
 DateTime start = new DateTime();  //NOW
 DateTime end = start.plus(<your period>);
 long millis = end.getMillis() - start.getMillis();
```

Answer (score 2):

Using Joda time 2.3, it is:

```
toStandardDuration().getMillis()
```