# How to test method with Calendar.getInstance()

Tags: java, testing

I have to calculate the time until the next day at ~ 2:00 AM

Following code seems to work fine

```
public static long millisTillNextDay() {
    Date now = new Date();
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + 1);
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR, 3);
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    return cal.getTimeInMillis() - now.getTime();
}
```

However, a few days ago it happened that this method calculated the time until 02:00 **PM** instead and I do not know why. Because of this I want to create some test scenarios to simulate different values for `Calendar.getInstance()`.

Comment: there might be a timezone change meanwhile on the machine this code run.

Comment: I would *strongly* advise you to use `java.time.*` instead of `java.util.Calendar`/`java.util.Date` if you *possibly* can. You've found *one* time-related bug in your code that probably wouldn't have happened using a better API... who knows how many more there may be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must set the `HOUR_OF_DAY` field instead of `HOUR`. The former doesn't mind the AM/PM distinction and always sets the absolute hour of the day.

Quotes from the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#HOUR_OF_DAY):

> HOUR is used for the 12-hour clock (0 - 11).
>
> HOUR_OF_DAY is used for the 24-hour clock.

Comment: Do you mean cal.set(Calendar.HOUR, 3); will set the hour to 2 PM if it is for example 6 PM and it will set it to 2 AM if it is 6 AM?

Comment: @stg Exactly. If you don't touch the `AM_PM` field, that is how the behavior is specified.

Comment: Thank you very much, I did not know this and will check this immediately.

Comment: I was able to verify this behavior, your answer solved my problem. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

For testing purposes, you could refactor the method to:

```
//the original method
public static long millisTillNextDay() {
    return millisTillNextDay(new Date());
}

//a new method that is testable
public static long millisTillNextDay(Date date) {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(date);
    cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + 1);
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR, 3);
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    return cal.getTimeInMillis() - date.getTime();
}
```

It now becomes easy to test the second method and pass in whatever dates you like.

Answer (score 1):

Just use one of the methods for Calendar that lets you specify the time.

For example:

```
long l = System.currentTimeMillis();
long limit = l + 24*60*60*1000;

for (long l = System.currentTimeMillis();l<=limit;l+=60*1000) {
    Calendar cal = new Calendar();
    cal.setTimeInMillis(l);
    // Do test
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a way to test, I suggest to change the method signature to accept `now` and then write a `TestCase` with `JUnit` injecting different dates. Like

```
public void MillisTillNextDayTest extends TestCase {
    public void testNewYearEveMidnight() {
        Date midnight = new Date(2014, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0);
        assertEquals(2*3600*1000, MyUtils.millisTillNextDay(midnight));
    }

    public void test3am() {
        Date now = new Date(2014, 0, 1, 3, 0, 0);
        assertEquals(23*3600*1000, MyUtils.millisTillNextDay(now));
    }

    public void test1pm() {
        Date now = new Date(2014, 0, 1, 13, 0, 0);
        assertEquals(13*3600*1000, MyUtils.millisTillNextDay(now));
    }

    public void testLeapYear() {
        Date now = new Date(2012, 1, 28, 13, 0, 0);
        assertEquals(13*3600*1000, MyUtils.millisTillNextDay(now));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Pacific/Auckland" ) ;
ZonedDateTime now = ZonedDateTime.now( z ) ;
Duration d = Duration.between( 
    now , 
    ZonedDateTime.of( 
        now.toLocalDate().plusDays(1) , 
        LocalTime.of( 2 , 0 )
        z 
    ) ;
).toString()
```

> PT8H32M57.264S

### Time-Zone

Other answers are correct except for one big flaw: time zone. All the code shown defaults to the JVM's current default time zone. When deploying code to another machine, you could have unexpected behavior. Daylight Saving Time (DST) or other anomalies tied to a time zone could alter the calculation.

## java.time

The modern approach uses the java.time classes.

A time zone is crucial in determining a date. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone. For example, a few minutes after midnight in [Paris France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe/Paris) is a new day while still “yesterday” in [Montréal Québec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal).

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
ZonedDateTime now = ZonedDateTime.now( z );
```

We need to build the target date-time, tomorrow at 2 AM. The tomorrow's date as a `LocalDate` (date-only value) plus the target time as a `LocalTime` (time-of-day only value). The java.time classes use 24-hour clock by default, so we needn't worry about your 2 AM vs 2 PM problem. A 2 PM values would have an input of 14 hours, so no ambiguity.

```
LocalDate tomorrow = now.toLocalDate().plusDays( 1 ) ;
LocalTime targetTime = LocalTime.of( 2 , 0 ) ;  // 2 hours, zero minutes.
```

Caveat: If you happened to pick a particular date and time that is invalid, such as a Daylight Saving Time (DST) cutover, the `ZonedDateTime` class adjusts to fit. Read the class documentation to see if its algorithms for adjusting fit your needs/expectations. For example, on the date of the DST "Spring-forward" date, you would end up with 3 AM rather than 2 AM as the 02:00 hour does not exist on that date, only 01:00 & 03:00 hours exist. This will *not* affect your calculation of a duration. The [space-time continuum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spacetime) did not jump, just our clock-on-the-wall representation jumped.

Put them together with the time zone to get 2 AM tomorrow.

```
ZonedDateTime target = ZonedDateTime.of( tomorrow , targetTime , z ) ;
```

Our ultimate goal it to capture the elapsed time between now and that target tomorrow. To represent a span-of-time unattached to the timeline, use the `Duration` or `Period` classes.

```
Duration d = Duration.between( now , target ) ;
```

Call `toString` to generate a String formatted according to the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations) standard, `PnYnMnDTnHnMnS`. The `P` marks the beginning, the `T` separates the years-months-days portion from the hours-minutes-seconds portion.

> PT8H32M57.264S

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

---

### Joda-Time

**UPDATE:** The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), with the team advising migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). This section here left intact for history.

Below is some example code using the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) 2.3 library.

The [`DateTime`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) class knows its own time zone.

The method [`withTime`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#withTime(int,%20int,%20int,%20int)) creates a new (immutable) instance copied from the existing instance, but with the specified time of day.

Joda-Time has a few classes to represent a span of time: [Period](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/Period.html), Duration, Interval. The Period class by defaults renders a string based on the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) [Duration format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations) of `PnYnMnDTnHnMnS`. You asked for milliseconds, so I calculate that in the example. See this question, [Joda time, Period to total millis](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9625306/642706), for more detail.

### Example Code

```java
// © 2013 Basil Bourque. This source code may be used freely forever by anyone taking full responsibility for doing so.
// import org.joda.time.*;

// Better to specify a time zone explicitly rather than rely on default.
// Time Zone list… http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/timezones.html  (not quite up-to-date, read page for details)
DateTimeZone timeZone = DateTimeZone.forID( "Europe/Paris" );

DateTime now = new DateTime( timeZone );
DateTime tomorrowTwoInMorning = now.plusDays( 1 ).withTime( 2, 0, 0, 0 );

// Calculate the span of time between them.
Period period = new Period( now, tomorrowTwoInMorning );
long milliseconds = period.toStandardDuration().getMillis();
```

Dump to console…

```java
System.out.println( "now: " + now );
System.out.println( "tomorrowTwoInMorning: " + tomorrowTwoInMorning );
System.out.println( "period: " + period );
System.out.println( "milliseconds: " + milliseconds );
```

When run…

```
now: 2014-01-11T00:51:38.059+01:00
tomorrowTwoInMorning: 2014-01-12T02:00:00.000+01:00
period: P1DT1H8M21.941S
milliseconds: 90501941
```